# Разница в часах между текущим временем в системе и региональным с помощью запроса Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно написать SQL запрос для нахождения интервала между временными метками в базе Oracle. Есть таблица с указанием регионального времени в формате hh:mm (только время). Необходимо найти разницу в часах между региональным временем и текущим временем, которое в системе. Пробовал найти решение в интернете, но все решения только с наличием дат в запросах, а здесь указана только временная отметка в формате hh:mm. Также пробовал предварительно склеить временную метку с текущей датой:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP as "Текущая дата"
    , Время_региона as "Время региона"
    ,(TO_DATE(SYSDATE + Время_региона)  - SYSTIMESTAMP) as "Часовая разница"
FROM Время
```

, но получаю ошибку в запросе.

Ниже показан скрин, на котором таблица "Время", красным выделен искомый результат.

[image: Таблица Время.]

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Oracle поддерживает лишь два типа данных для даты-времени - это DATE и TIMESTAMP. Ну есть ещё INTERVAL. Значение, показанное на скриншоте, ни одному из них не соответствует, это явно строковое значение. Так что прибавлять его без соотв. конвертации к SYSDATE несколько самонадеянно..

Answer (score 0):

нашел решение вопроса следующим запросом:

```
    SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP as "Текущая дата"
    , Время_региона as "Время региона"
    , ROUND(
            (CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP( TO_CHAR(SYSDATE) || ' ' || Время_региона || ':00',  'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AS DATE) 
            - CAST( SYSTIMESTAMP AS DATE) + 730487)
            * 24
            ) as "Часовая разница"

FROM Время
```

только пришлось прописать константу 730487 (дней), не смог найти объяснение этой константе.

Comment: 730487 - это примерно 2000 лет, наверное потому что ваш `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE)` возвращает двузначный год.